# SQLite Python Query: ORDER BY DESC not working?

Tags: python, sql

```
conn = sqlite3.connect('Path_To_DB.db')
c = conn.cursor() 
    c.execute('SELECT Nick,NumCount,TimesRun FROM databaseTable ORDER BY NumCount desc')
    ordered = c.fetchall()
    print ordered
```

Of course, this is just a snippet but the printed "ordered" doesn't show up... well, ordered.

To be more exact, this is my output

```
    [(u'Coburn', u'52', 1), (u'radii', u'295', 1), (u'Senna_Wong', u'242', 1), (u'sinkingwork', u'17', 1), (u'Yumirose', u'164', 1), (u'yepperoni', u'154', 1), (u'Jeffrey-sama', 861, 2), (u'Kethsar', 414, 5), (u'sakeisgood', 331, 2), (u'lygerzero0zero', 269, 2), (u'asdfjjjjjj', 268, 5), (u'lunr', 253, 3), (u'asdfasf', 237, 2), (u'asdfsadjf', 130, 2), (u'Neibs', 107, 2)]
```

It's an XChat IRC plugin script so I need to extract the database values to show a "top score" list. I've been contemplating manually sorting it but that takes a lot of extra effort and since I'm new to python scripting, a lot of time and research as well. (I was thinking of grabbing the SELECT queries separately, combining them in a large list[a,b,c] and sorting via that.)

So anyway, the question is: What the heck am I doing wrong so the count isn't being sorted correctly?

Answer (score 3):

Half of them are strings, which sort differently. Scrub your data, converting the strings to numbers.

Comment: Ah. That was the issue. I sort of started SQL two days ago as well ^^;

Answer (score 1):

The problem is you have different types of data.  Look at he NumCount fields, see the quote marks around some but not others?  I think if you change all the strings to numbers you will have solved the trouble.

Comment: Thanks, as Ignacio pointed out, the datatypes were inconsistent. I'd set the number to be cast as strings earlier before I started implementing the "high score" functionality as it was only used to output in an outbound message to the IRC server. Thanks!